# Set breakpoint on protocol method

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, breakpoints, lldb

Basically I need to set a breakpoint on a protocol method in order to catch all calls to objects conforming to that protocol. I have a custom framework with lots of classes conforming to the protocol, so manually setting a breakpoint on every class is not feasible.

I tried setting the breakpoint from the Xcode editor:

[image]

, however when setting the breakpoint I get only breakpoints for the allocation methods:
[image: allocation breakpoints]

, and as expected the debugger doesn't stop when `doSomething()` is called.

I also tried adding symbolic breakpoints, no luck here too:
[image]

Here's some demo code to illustrate this:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    func doSomething()
    func doAnotherThing()
}

class TestConformingClass: TestProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        print("Yay")
    }

    func doAnotherThing() {
        print("Hooray")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to intercept all calls to a method that is part of a protocol requirements list?

Comment: Besides having _lots_ of types conforming to the protocol, do you also have lots of methods that you want to break on, and lots of call sites where these methods are invoked? If the answer to both questions is no, you could go for a quick-and-dirty debug-only solution, add a wrapper method for your to-be-observed method in a protocol extension, set your breakpoint in this wrapper, and call the wrapper instead of the real method from your client code. If the answer was yes, then.. nevermind :)

Comment: @dr_barto a Decorator might do the trick, however I also have a  lot of call sites for the method I'm interested into. So the question to both questions is unfortunately yes. There only one method I want to break on, however I have lots of implementations and lots of callers, and both numbers are expected to grow in the near future

Comment: In lldb, did can you please try out the following: 
breakpoint set --name doSomething

Comment: @MehulParmar thanks for the suggestion, I will try it later, ATM I don't have access to a mac with xcode

Comment: @MehulParmar it works, can you add an answer with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running the following command in lldb  should do the trick:

```
breakpoint set --name doSomething
breakpoint set --name doAnotherThing
```

Possibly, even the following might work:

```
breakpoint set --name doSomething --name doAnotherThing
```

Comment: Note that if you find these breakpoints catching too many unrelated functions of the same name, you can use `--language swift` to restrict the matches to only swift symbols and/or use `--shlib <NAME_OF_YOUR_BINARY>` to restrict the search to the binary that implements the methods you want to stop in.  `--shlib` can also be provided more than once to restrict the search to a set of shared libraries.